# MDI object oriented approach, retrieving this pointer from MDICREATESTRUCT

Tags: c++, winapi, mdi

I'm trying to implement MDI Child window base class, according [to this reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagmdicreatestructa) details on remarks say

> When the MDI client window creates an MDI child window by calling
>   CreateWindow, the system sends a WM_CREATE message to the created
>   window. The lParam member of the WM_CREATE message contains a pointer
>   to a CREATESTRUCT structure. The lpCreateParams member of this
>   structure contains a pointer to the MDICREATESTRUCT structure passed
>   with the WM_MDICREATE message that created the MDI child window.

I'm using following simple base template class to create MDI child window, implementing above statements to retrieve this pointer. (added few comments)

**basemdi.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <Windows.h>

template <typename DERIVED_TYPE>
class BaseMDI
{
public:
    inline HWND GetHandle() const;
    BOOL Initialize(
        PCTSTR szWindowName,
        HWND hParent,
        DWORD dwExStyle = WS_EX_MDICHILD, // THIS IS MDI WINDOW
        DWORD dwStyle = 0,
        int x = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int y = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int width = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        int height = CW_USEDEFAULT,
        HMENU hMenu = nullptr,
        HINSTANCE hInstance = GetModuleHandle(nullptr),
        LPVOID lpCreate = nullptr
    );

protected:
    virtual PCTSTR ClassName() const = 0;
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    virtual LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) = 0;

    HWND m_hwnd = nullptr;
};

template<typename DERIVED_TYPE>
BOOL BaseMDI<DERIVED_TYPE>::Initialize(
    PCTSTR szWindowName,
    HWND hParent,
    DWORD dwExStyle,
    DWORD dwStyle,
    int x,
    int y,
    int width,
    int height,
    HMENU hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID lpCreate)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCreate);

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { };

    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    MDICREATESTRUCT mdicreate;

    // ASSIGN POINTER TO THIS SO THAT WE LATER RETRIEVE IT
    mdicreate.lParam = (LPARAM) this;

    mdicreate.szClass = ClassName();
    mdicreate.szTitle = TEXT("Hello");
    mdicreate.hOwner = hInstance;
    mdicreate.x = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mdicreate.y = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mdicreate.cx = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mdicreate.cy = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    mdicreate.style = dwStyle;

    m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(
        dwExStyle,
        ClassName(),
        szWindowName,
        dwStyle,
        x, y,
        width,
        height,
        hParent,
        hMenu,
        hInstance,
        &mdicreate // PASS ADDRESS OF MDICREATESTRUCT
    );

    return m_hwnd ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
// following base class WndProc calls derived class procedure, 
// I retrive this pointer here to call correct procedure, but pThis is read acess vioalaiton
template<typename DERIVED_TYPE>
inline LRESULT BaseMDI<DERIVED_TYPE>::WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    DERIVED_TYPE* pThis = nullptr;

    if (uMsg == WM_CREATE)
    {
        // RETRIEVE POINTER TO THIS
        CREATESTRUCT* pCreate = reinterpret_cast<CREATESTRUCT*>(lParam);
        MDICREATESTRUCT* pMdi = reinterpret_cast<MDICREATESTRUCT*>(pCreate->lpCreateParams);
        pThis = reinterpret_cast<DERIVED_TYPE*>(pMdi->lParam);
        SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA, reinterpret_cast<LONG_PTR>(pThis));

        pThis->m_hwnd = hWnd;
    }
    else
    {
        pThis = reinterpret_cast<DERIVED_TYPE*>(GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
    }

    if (pThis)
    {
        // EXCEPTION IS THROWN HERE
        return pThis->HandleMessage(uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    else
    {
        return DefMDIChildProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}

template <typename DERIVED_TYPE>
HWND BaseMDI<DERIVED_TYPE>::GetHandle() const
{
    return m_hwnd;
}
```

Here is how I create an actual instance of the MDI child window object, the class inherits above templated base class

**mdiwindow.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "mdibase.h"

class MDI : public BaseMDI<MDI>
{
public:
    virtual LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) override;

private:
    inline virtual PCTSTR ClassName() const override;
};

PCTSTR MDI::ClassName() const
{
    return TEXT("MDIWindow");
}
```

**mdiwindow.cpp**

```
 #include "mdiwindow.h"


LRESULT MDI::HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    default:
        return DefMDIChildProc(m_hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

When the MDI child is created I got exception in basemdi.h saying **read access violation** for pThis pointer.

I'm folowing msdn instructions on how to retrieve pointer to `MDICREATESTRUCT` that is passed to `CreateWindowEx`, which holds pointer to `this` in `lpCreateParams` but for some reason the retrieved pointer doesn't work.

Do you see what could be cause for this?

Comment: Note that MDI is deprecated, it probably doesn't make sense to develop new apps with this interface.

Comment: didn't know that, what is the replacement API for MDI?

Comment: The "modern" UI interface is tabs, there isn't really an API as such (not in Win32 anyway).

Comment: but tabs don't arrange them self like MDI child windows so that all can be visible in single interface, ex: tile and cascade. I'm confused by your statement, because MS Excel which is modern application, uses MDI for arranging excel books inside client window. I can't see tabs as superior to MDI. lack of MDI functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.

the issue is that MSDN is talking about posibility to use `CreateWindow` or `CreateWindowEx` which won't work for child MDI windows, one need to use `CreateMDIWindow` instead!

here is the working Initialize function from above example, the rest of the code from above is fine:

```
template<typename DERIVED_TYPE>
BOOL BaseMDI<DERIVED_TYPE>::Initialize(
    PCTSTR szWindowName,
    HWND hParent,
    DWORD dwExStyle,
    DWORD dwStyle,
    int x,
    int y,
    int width,
    int height,
    HMENU hMenu,
    HINSTANCE hInstance,
    LPVOID lpCreate)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCreate);

    WNDCLASSEX wc = { };

    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH));
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hIcon = nullptr;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = ClassName();
    wc.lpszMenuName = nullptr;
    wc.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) abort();

    m_hwnd = CreateMDIWindow(
        ClassName(),
        szWindowName,
        dwStyle,
        x, y,
        width,
        height,
        hParent,
        hInstance,
        (LPARAM)this);

    if (!m_hwnd) abort();

    return m_hwnd ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Comment: for what you use template here ?

Comment: also what you need - add `virtual LRESULT DefWinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);` to your class. in current implementation you need diferent base classes for mdichild, mdiframe and usual window (because all it use different default window proc). with virtual it - you can use common base class for all windows types. and of course not need any templates

Comment: Your advice sounds logical, but I'm not sure how to implement it, can you post example code for base class with virtual DefWinProc without template please?

Comment: template you not need at all - cast all pointers to base class and call virtual functions. simply add to base class `virtual LRESULT DefWinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);` and call it form base class `HandleMessage`. for normal window implementation of `DefWinProc` will be call `::DefWindowProc`, inherit classes for mdi frame and child and frame from base. and overrite it `DefWindowProc` implementation for call `DefMDIChildProc` and `DefFrameProc`

Comment: also `CreateWindowEx` work of course for create MDI child and frame too. you need use `WS_EX_MDICHILD` extended style for create child

Comment: During WM_CREATE in base class pointer to this is retrieved by casting to CREATESTRUCT, and for MDI child casting to CREATESTRUCT first and then to MDICREATESTRUCT, how do you plan to manage 2 kinds of castings in single base class? also I did use WS_EX_MDICHILD to create MDI child but saved this pointer didn't work it throwed exeption.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and problem with virtual LRESULT DefWinProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) is that function must be static to be called in static WindowProc, and because it's static it can't be overriden in derived class.

Comment: it must be called from `HandleMessage`. anyway you have here (in static WindowProc too)  pointer to class. also better use another, universal, way for bind window to class - set in tls pointer to your class before call CreateWindowExW, inside __WindowProc - got this pointer from tls, SetWindowLongPtr , and change window procedure tp another, say _WindowProc - which just GetWindowLongPtr

Answer (score 0):

I was recently using MDI with an OOP approach for fun and this works for me:

```
    MDICREATESTRUCT mcs;
    mcs.szTitle = WindowText();
    mcs.szClass = ClassName();
    mcs.hOwner = GetModuleHandle( nullptr );
    mcs.x = x;
    mcs.y = y;
    mcs.cx = width;
    mcs.cy = height;
    mcs.style = dwStyle;
    mcs.lParam = reinterpret_cast< LPARAM >( this );

    mSubWnd = reinterpret_cast< HWND >( SendMessage( hParent, WM_MDICREATE, 0, reinterpret_cast< LONG >( &mcs ) ) );
```